# Constraints in Jetpack Compose is not working properly

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-constraintlayout

I have a simple Text and Image in the `ConstraintLayout` in Compose. Here's the code :

```
@Composable
fun ImageView() {
    ConstraintLayout(modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()) {
        val (text, image) = createRefs()
        Text(text = "Test", color = Color.White, modifier = Modifier.constrainAs(text){
            top.linkTo(parent.top)
        })
        Image(painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_date), contentDescription = "", modifier = Modifier.constrainAs(image){
            top.linkTo(text.bottom)
            start.linkTo(anchor = text.start)
        })


    }
}
```

I want the image to start exactly from where the text starts. So I gave `start.linkTo(anchor = text.start)`. But this is what I got :

[image]

I think the image itself has some space at the start. But I wonder why the constraints don't work. Please help.

Comment: your image resource has transparent padding. you need to edit it somehow

Comment: @PylypDukhov If I use the same image resource in xml and set the constraints, it would align perfectly as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Dimension.fillToConstraints`.

By default the width and height of `ConstrainsLayout` **child** is `Dimension.wrapContent`.

You can change like this:

```
Modifier.constrainAs(view){
    width = Dimension.fillToConstraints
    height = Dimension.fillToConstraints
}
```

Try this:

```
@Composable
fun ImageView() {
    ConstraintLayout(modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()) {
        val (text, image) = createRefs()
        Text(text = "Test", color = Color.White, modifier = Modifier.constrainAs(text){
            top.linkTo(parent.top)
        })
        Image(painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_date), contentDescription = "", modifier = Modifier.constrainAs(image){
            top.linkTo(text.bottom)
            start.linkTo(anchor = text.start)
            width = Dimension.fillToConstraints
        })
    }
}
```